# Does DBCC CHECKDB block SQL backups?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Will "DBCC CHECKDB" block TSQL "BACKUP DATABASE" ?

Will TSQL "BACKUP DATABASE" block "DBCC CHECKDB"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, after a lot of improvements over the years to the DBCC CHECKDB command, it no longer explicitly takes out locks and it does not specifically block backups. Here's a good article about it: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (2/30) DBCC CHECKDB causes blocking](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-230-dbcc-checkdb-causes-blocking/)

The only issue to be aware of is that the DBCC CHECKDB command can be resource intensive and backups can also be resource intensive. So it is possible to run into resource contention that causes your backups to run slower while actively running DBCC CHECKDB.